# How to interpolate message dynamically in ConstraintValidator with property node?

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

Assume I have simple dto with one field and this dto is also annotated with custom validation annotation:

```
@CustomAnnotation
public class SimpleDto {
    private String field;
}
// setters and getters omited
```

Custom annotation:

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface CheckMondialRelayShopOrderWeight {
    String message() default "{temp.key.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and finally validator itself:

```
public class CustomValidator implements
    ConstraintValidator<CustomAnnotation, SimpleDto> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomAnnotation constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(SimpleDto value, 
                        ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext = context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
            hibernateContext.addMessageParameter("dynamicValue", 130);
            hibernateContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(hibernateContext.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate()).addPropertyNode("field").addConstraintViolation().disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in application.properties:

```
CustomAnnotation.simpleDto.field=Your dynamic value is {dynamicValue}
```

But this doesn't work, this works just fine if I put `hibernateContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Your dynamic value is {dynamicValue}").addConstraintViolation().disableDefaultConstraintViolation();` instead of `hibernateContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(hibernateContext.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate()).addPropertyNode("field").addConstraintViolation().disableDefaultConstraintViolation();`

I can't figure out how to use the interpolation with addPropertyNode. Any suggestions?